# inner join in java using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two List Map:

orders

```
[
    {
        item_id=1, 
        item=item-1, 
        user_id=1
    },
    {
        item_id=2, 
        item=item-2, 
        user_id=2
    }, 
    {
        item_id=3, 
        item=item-3, 
        user_id=3
    }
]
```

users

```
[
    {
        user_id=1, 
        name=abh, 
        email=abh@bit.com
    }, 
    {
        user_id=2, 
        name=pol, 
        email=pol@bit.com
    }, 
    {
        user_id=3, 
        name=tre, 
        email=tre@bit.com
    }
]
```

They are initialized as

```
List<Map<String, String>> data
```

I want to do an sql equivalent inner join on this List Maps using Streams.

I tried this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> collect = leftData.stream().flatMap(t1 -> rightData.stream())
                .filter(t -> t.get(joinColumnTableLeft).equals(t.get(joinColumnTableRight)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This gives me a result of size size(users) * size(orders), which is 9. 
And the collect has `orders`.

But I want both the Map to merged into single and then create a list out of it.

Cannot use any library as of now.

Comment: how they initialised as `List<Map<String, String>> data`, can you provide the code for that?

Comment: Create a Map<UserId, User> from the second list. Then iterate through the first list, and for each element, find the user by user ID using the Map<UserId, User>. You really should start defining classes instead of storing data into maps.

Comment: @JBNizet I know, but I'm writing a generic csv parser. Hence I have to work with Maps

Comment: Well, do just what I said, but using maps instead of proper objects.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that.. :/

Comment: Transform the second list into a map `usersById`, where each element of the list is an entry of the map, with the userId as key, and the element itself is the value, i.e. a Map<String, Map<String, String>>. Then iterate over the first list. For each element, get the userId out of it, then find the user map from `usersById`, and merge the two maps.

Comment: If `joinColumnTableLeft` equals `joinColumnTableRight`, then also `t.get(joinColumnTableLeft).equals(t.get(joinColumnTableRight))`, which explains why you got the cross product (all 9 possible combinations). You need two different `t`s in that comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have duplicate entries (by the merge column key), you can use a method like this to merge.

This creates a map of the `mergeColumn` key to the full map by row in one of the lists, then uses that for lookup when merging by iterating through the other map.

```
static List<Map<String, String>> merge(List<Map<String, String>> left, 
       List<Map<String, String>> right, String joinColumnTableLeft,
       String joinColumnTableRight) {

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> rightById = right.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get(joinColumnTableRight), 
                                      Function.identity()));

    return left.stream()
               .filter(e -> rightById.containsKey(e.get(joinColumnTableLeft)))
               .map(l -> {
                 Map<String, String> all = new HashMap<>();
                 all.putAll(l);
                 all.putAll(rightById.get(l.get(joinColumnTableLeft)));

                 return all;
               })
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As a test:

```
Map<String, String> left1 = new HashMap<>(), right1 = new HashMap<>();
left1.put("a", "A");
left1.put("b", "B");
left1.put("c", "C");

right1.put("a", "A");
right1.put("d", "B");

Map<String, String> left2 = new HashMap<>(), right2 = new HashMap<>();
left2.put("a", "AA");
left2.put("b", "BB");
left2.put("c", "CC");

right2.put("a", "AA");
right2.put("d", "BB");

System.out.println(merge(Arrays.asList(left1, left2), 
        Arrays.asList(right1, right2), "a", "a"));
```

The output is: `[{a=A, b=B, c=C, d=B}, {a=AA, b=BB, c=CC, d=BB}]`

The order of entries isn't important, though. Just note that this assumes that there are no overlapping keys other than the join column. Otherwise, you may want to collect pairs of maps instead of calling `putAll` on a new map.

---

The following will support duplicate join keys (and will produce a cartesian product for all entries per key):

```
static List<Map<String, String>> merge(List<Map<String, String>> left, 
        List<Map<String, String>> right,
        String joinColumnTableLeft, String joinColumnTableRight) {

    Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> rightById = right.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get(joinColumnTableRight)));

    return left.stream()
            .filter(e -> rightById.containsKey(e.get(joinColumnTableLeft)))
            .flatMap(l -> rightById.get(l.get(joinColumnTableLeft)).stream()
                    .map(r -> {
                                Map<String, String> all = new HashMap<>();
                                all.putAll(l);
                                all.putAll(r);

                                return all;
                            }
                    )
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I got `IllegalStateException:  duplicate key` when I have a user_id twice in orders. user_id=3, user_id=3